# Confidence interval for Repeatability from a lme mixed model

Tags: confidence-interval, mixed-model, uncertainty, repeatability

I have a (lme) mixed model of this type:

```
model=lme(trait1~tl_s+year+month_s+I(month_s^2)+I(month_s^3),random=~1|ID,correlation=corAR1(form=~tim),data=depm3,method="REML")
```

I'm interested in estimating the repeatability of the trait I'm modelling (trait1 in this case). I get a point estimate with this code:

```
R=as.numeric(VarCorr(mod))[1]/(as.numeric(VarCorr(mod))[1]+as.numeric(VarCorr(mod))[2])
```

But what would be the code to extract confidence interval for R estimate? I read that parametric bootstrapping would be an option here, but I don't really know how to implement it.
I have check some recent posts on the topic like this one...

[How to calculate estimated proportions and their confidence intervals from a mixed model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70817/how-to-calculate-estimated-proportions-and-their-confidence-intervals-from-a-mix)

...but I haven't really found the answer to my question.

Any advise would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: There is no package to deal with lme repeatability when it includes autocorrelation and variance functions. I tried to make the function myself using the boot function for bootstrapping in order to get the confidence intervals. However, the question here is: does the autocorrelation and variance function remain valid for the new dataset after bootstrapping??

Answer (score 0):

There is no package to deal with `lme` repeatability when it includes autocorrelation and/or variance functions. I tried to code the function myself using the `boot()` function for bootstrapping in order to get the confidence intervals.

```
library(boot)

rsq <- function(formula,cor.b,weights.b,random.b, data,indices) {

    d <- data[indices,] # allows boot to select sample

    fit <- lme(formula, data=d,correlation=cor.b,weights=weights.b,random=random.b)

    VarComps=VarCorr(fit)

    var_G <-as.numeric(as.character(VarComps[1,1]))

    var_R <- as.numeric(as.character(VarComps[2,1]))

    var_P <- sum(as.numeric(VarComps [,1]))

    R=var_G / var_P

    return(R)

} 
results <- boot(data=depm3, statistic=rsq, R=2, formula=trait1~tl_s+year+month_s+I(month_s^2)+I(month_s^3), random.b=~1|ID, cor.b=corAR1(form=~tim))

boot.ci(results, type="bca") #to get confidence intervals
```

Usually, R should be around 1000 but it will take too long to be done.

However, the question here is: does the autocorrelation and variance function remain valid for the new dataset after bootstrapping?